# Scrapy recursively scraping craigslist

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I am using scrapy to scrap craigslist and get all links, go to that link, store the description for each page and email for reply. Now I have written a scrapy script which gors through the craigslist/sof.com and gets all job titles and urls. I want to go inside each url and save the email and description per job. Heres my code :

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist.items import CraigslistItem

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["craigslist.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://sfbay.craigslist.org/npo/"]
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        titles = hxs.select("//span[@class='pl']")
        for titles in titles:
                title = titles.select("a/text()").extract()
                link = titles.select("a/@href").extract()
                desc = titles.select("a/replylink").extract
                print link, title
```

Any ideas how to do this ?

Comment: How to do what exactly?  Is there something wrong with your code or do you need more code?

Comment: I need more code. This code is fine. I want to recurse through the link and then scrap data of those links.

Answer (score 1):

scrapy functions should yield (or return) [Item/s](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html) and [Request/s](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html)

a returned Item will be [pipelined](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) according to configuration, next spider step is determined by returning a Request with a reference to the function in the callback field

from scrapy documentation:

```
def parse_page1(self, response):
    return Request("http://www.example.com/some_page.html",
                      callback=self.parse_page2)

def parse_page2(self, response):
    # this would log http://www.example.com/some_page.html
    self.log("Visited %s" % response.url)
```

Answer (score 1):

Scraping craigslist is illegal as per their policy:

> Robots, spiders, scripts, scrapers, crawlers, etc. are prohibited

source: https://www.craigslist.org/about/terms.of.use

Now their API is another question, however that only gets updated every hour (so there's a lag time of 1 hour).